# In Python should we set Optional[str] = None in the argument list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My coworker said the code I wrote crashed recently and that was because in the function's argument list I did not specify `Optional[str] = None`. I only have `Optional[str]`.

So basically my function looks like this:

```
def a(b: Optional[str]):
    if b is None:
        <do something>
    else:
        <do something>
```

I always thought default for Optional argument is None, so I did not specify the default value. It did not crash for me but crashed for my coworker, so I'm kinda confused.

My python version is >=3.

Comment: What do you mean `crashed`? Are you both running the same python version?

Comment: That is a type-hint, not a default argument, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Your function signature describes a function that requires a single argument that may be either a `str` or `None`.  If you try to invoke it with `a()`, it fill fail because of a missing argument.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comments, `Optional[str]` is a type-hint to be used by IDEs and other static analysis tools, not a default argument.  If you want to make a default argument such that you can call the function with `a()`, then you do need to add `= None` as you proposed.  That could be a reasonable approach if you expect this function to be called with an omitted argument, but that will depend on your design and architecture.